# Linux Copy Files in Mount Location Very Slow

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

In RHEL 5.5 Linux, I have a Folder //ELG which is a Mount location on shared Directory //AMC [ type cifs (rw,mand)]

Inside //ELG/X1/SMART001 there are 3 files of 200 MB size

- //ELG/X1/SMART001/A1.odf 60MB
- //ELG/X1/SMART001/A2.odf 70MB
- //ELG/X1/SMART001/A3.odf 70MB

I am using the below command to Copy contents from One folder to other from shell

cp -R "//ELG/X1/SMART001" "//ELG/X1/VIA001"

This is taking a lot of time (more than 1 hr) to perform the Copy.

Am I doing something wrong here? is there an alternative and faster way to perform this? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a different IO scheduler. I once had a similar problem with external  devices (with a different filesystem, though). Write access was terribly slow. Please note that I'm on Ubuntu and not sure where RHEL is different (however a few minutes of googling show that it seems to be roughly the same).

The following code works on my Ubuntu, please check what the RHEL analogy is:

The default IO scheduler is CFQ, you could try "deadline".

To list the available io schedulers use this command.

```
cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler
```

This should return `noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]`

To change your scheduler to deadline use the following command on the appropriate device.

```
sudo echo "deadline" > /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler
```

You can read more about it here: [RHEL IO Scheduler](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Kernel_Boot_Parameters-The_IO_Scheduler.html)